# Samsung monitor won't stop cycling inputs

Tags: display

My old Samsung T260 monitor was working great until yesterday. It's now unusable as it won't stay on one source. It looks like it's cycling through all the sources digital, analog, hdmi and won't stay on one. Even with nothing plugged into it, it continuously cycles through all the inputs.

I suspect the source button is stuck down but it still clicks when I press it. Any other reasons it would do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have a Samsung Syncmaster E2220 with the exact same problem.

The best suggestion I got was to remove the front panel (with the buttons). Then the monitor supposedly should still work, and should automatically get turned on by the computer.

However, this feels a little extreme, so if there is a better solution, I'm all ears (or eyes I guess).

Thanks!

EDIT: I opened up the monitor and disconnected the board containing the buttons. This did solve the problem. The monitor is now usable, although it isn't ideal, since you can't change any settings (or to turn it off and on. This might be possible to do through the PC.

Comment: Interesting solution. I will give it a try.